# Android Json data(output from mysqli) is not working in TextView

Tags: php, android, json, android-volley

I am doing some basic test for displaying json data that's output from PHP mysqli into TextView.

```
TextView mTxtDisplay;

String url = "http://192.168.1.102/web_service/test.php/";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mTxtDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    mTxtDisplay.setText(response.toString());
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(jsObjRequest);
}}
```

**192.168.1.102/web_service/test.php**

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM item where uid='1'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$myArray = array();
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $myArray[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($myArray);
}
```

**output**

```
[{"iid":"482","uid":"1","item_id":"1","item_name":"Chicken Rice","item_price":"1","item_quantity":"1","status":"0"},
{"iid":"483","uid":"1","item_id":"1","item_name":"French Fries","item_price":"1","item_quantity":"1","status":"0"},
{"iid":"484","uid":"1","item_id":"1","item_name":"apple","item_price":"1","item_quantity":"1","status":"0"},
{"iid":"492","uid":"1","item_id":"1","item_name":"western+italian","item_price":"1","item_quantity":"1","status":"0"},
{"iid":"493","uid":"1","item_id":"1","item_name":"no_cat","item_price":"1","item_quantity":"1","status":"0"}]
```

I think my json is correct? But it simply doesn't display in Textview, **it's EMPTY! without any errors** .

After that, I realized data in the below format is working well(normal hard code Array).

```
{
"1":{"name":"Superman","date":"20160909","location":"Mars"},
"2":{"name":"Xman","date":"20160909","location":"Galaxy"},
"3":{"name":"Batman","date":"20160909","location":"Earth"}
}
```

**So that means the second json data without "[]" works fine but the first json data with "[]" is not working. But this shouldn't be the way right?**

What's wrong with the coding?

Comment: are you getting response from your web api or not? If response is coming then it should show, if not then check what is the error it is giving?

Comment: @SilvansSolanki it has nothing to do with whether its api or not. The error is just like what Nayan mentioned below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because data within `[]` is `JSONArray` not `JSONObject`. Instead of JSONObjectRequest try StringRequest and then print your response into EditText/TextView. You can access elements of your array to by converting them into JSONArray.

```
JSONArray arr=new JSONArray(response);
```

Comment: can you show the coding for changing to JsonArrayRequest? I tried but got some errors.

Comment: Instead of JSONObjectRequest try StringRequest and then convert response to JSONArray

Answer (score 1):

Instead of JSONObjectRequest trying using StringRequest your code will be something like this:

```
        StringRequest jsonReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String s) {
         Log.d("Response", s);
         textView.setText(s)
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
         //do error code here..
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getParams(){
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("param1", value);
            return params;
        }
    };
```

getParams is used for sending request to server with some user defined values or to get some specific data at run time.